# How do you use a POST URI in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, get, uri

I am trying to use a POST URI in my code to access NCBO's Annotator tool. My current code is a GET request, but I don't know how to format this into a POST request. My data is the text variable.

All the examples which I've seen uses `request.get(url) -> request.post(url, data=data)`, but how can I do this for `build_opener()` and `json.loads()`?

Here is my code:

```
def get_json(url):
#get annotations
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('Authorization', 'apikey token=' + API_KEY)]
    return json.loads(opener.open(url).read())

text = "random text with a lot of words"
annotations = get_json("http://data.bioontology.org/annotator?text=" + urllib.parse.quote(text))
```

Updated code:

```
def get_annotations(text, url):
    headers = [('Authorization', 'apikey token=' + API_KEY)]
    data = text

    response = requests.request("POST",url,headers=headers,data=data)
    return response.text.encode('utf-8')

annotations = get_annotations(text, "http://data.bioontology.org/annotator?text=" + urllib.parse.quote(text))
```

Error:

```
    response = requests.request("POST",url,headers=headers,data=data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 516, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 449, in prepare_request
    p.prepare(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 315, in prepare
    self.prepare_headers(headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 447, in prepare_headers
    for header in headers.items():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to import requests module, this module is easy to choose request method.

```
import requests
def get_json(url):
    headers = [('Authorization', 'apikey token=' + API_KEY)]  #add headers here
    data = #params you want to send

    response = requests.request("POST",url,headers=headers,data=data)  #you can choose your methods here.
    return response.text.encode('utf-8')
```

FYR simply like this.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your response! I tried out the code and I got an Attribute Error (edited my original post to add the new code + error message). 

When I access the page, I need to put the text in the URL like this: "...?text=" + data.
When using POST, does it automatically fill in that missing text part?